# Ionic cordova run android not generating apk

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, apk

I am trying to deploy the .apk file doing the command:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

The problem is that I don't recieve any error, it says that the app is generated, but on my device, the one is conected with an USB is never recieving the app.

The warnings I got are:

```
ANDROID_HOME=D:\Program Files (x86)\sdk-tools-windows-3859397
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk-9.0.4
(node:9940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or 
 greater
(node:9940) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will 
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

What could it be? Any advice would be appreciated it.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk-9.0.4` try using JDK version 8 instead of 9...

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Android Studio. Open your ionic project platform folder using android studio. then try to run android emulator. If it works fine. then you can try on your mobile device. The android device must be in developer mode to run it.